# Split landscape PDF into portrait pages

Tags: pdf

I am given a couple PDF files which are created using LaTeX in a landscape format. On my 24" monitor, I can comfortably read them full screen, but it is a pain to use when the windows is smaller, like on my Netbook.

Is there some way to split this PDF up into several landscape pages?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Briss](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/)

It does a wonderful job at this even though it is not too user-friendly.

- Download the archive and extract it somewhere.
- Create a briss.sh script file containing the following code in the same folder:

> cd ~/path/to/briss
>
> java -Xmx128m -D java.library.path=. -jar briss-0.9.jar

- Browse to the folder where you created the script, right-click on the script, click properties, permissions tab, tick **Allow executing file as program**.
- run the script by double-clicking it.

Comment: Works pretty well, just complains that it cannot display the produced PDF. The file is still there.

Comment: I never had this issue. MAybe it is a question of your default pdf viewer.

Answer (score 1):

1. pdftk burst: will convert the pdf file into number pdfs.
2. imagemagick convert and crop: create tiff files of left and right side
3. imagemagic convert *.tif outfile.pdf : creates a single outfile.pdf from all the tif files

This will be easy to do in a little shell script.

Comment: Converting the text to tiff and back will make the files huge and the quality inferior.